# Use of require and referencing gem objects

Tags: ruby

Beginner Ruby question here...

I'm using the AWS SDK, when I want to access an S3 resource I use:

```
Aws::S3::Resource.new
```

Given this code is from the `aws-sdk` gem, shouldn't I need:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
```

At the top of my file?

Seems to work without this so I'm just curious of the best practice and when I actually need to require things. Or if I'm just going about it in the complete wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the kernel method `require` is very simple. It *runs* the file being `require`d, but only once. For example, there are 2 ruby script files:

**foo.rb**

```
puts 'foo'
```

**main.rb**

```
require '/path/to/foo.rb'
require '/path/to/foo.rb'
```

When you run `ruby main.rb`, you will see it prints `foo` only once, although it is required twice.

It is a common situation that a ruby script file defines a module or a class in it. `require`-ing such files loads the modules/classes into memory.

You said that `require 'aws-sdk'` sometimes can be omitted, that's because `bundler` has already done the `require` job for you.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

**Somewhere in your booting logic**

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default
```

The combination of the 3 lines of code did the trick.